# JQuery change select option when text input like value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a text input and a select element.

my select option values are all numbers but the displays are product names.

how can i make the selected option change when a user types in a text input or changes the text input but i want to choose the option in the select element where the display is like the value in the text input

```js
// Event handler for text input
$('#txt').on('input', function() {
  // Getiing option based on input value and setting it as selected
  $('#sel option:contains(' + this.value + ')').eq(0).prop('selected', true);
});

// Event handler for select
$('#sel').change(function() {
  // Updating text input based on selected value
  $('#txt').val($('option:selected', this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<select id="sel">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value=1>Domain Registration (.co.uk)</option>
  <option value=2>Domain Registration (.co)</option>
  <option value=3>Domain Registration (.com)</option>
  <option value=2>Domain Registration (.uk.com)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What would the user be typing in the input? Numbers that correspond with the select option values or product names?

Comment: the user would be typing product names

Comment: use a jquery event to build your logic...what have you tried

Comment: Have you tried to do it? What have you tried? Post your code and tell us where you failed.

Comment: i wasnt really sure, i only got as far as checking when the text input value is changed. i was unsure how to search the select options where the input val was LIKE the option name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach it like this,

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input">

<select id="selectId">
    <option value="1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="2">Product 2</option>
    <option value="3">Product 3</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input").change(function(){
        var val = $("#input").val();
        $("#selectId > option").each(function() {
            if(this.text == val) {
                $("#selectId > option").removeAttr("selected");
                $(this).attr("selected","selected");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Please find the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chirag1goel/Lvn9vfcx/1/

EDIT: With sub-string matching.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input").change(function(){
        var val = $("#input").val();
        $("#selectId > option").each(function() { //Run through the loop of each option
            if(this.text.indexOf(val)>=0) { //Find if the string present as substring
                $("#selectId > option").removeAttr("selected"); //Remove the existing selected option
                $(this).attr("selected","selected"); //Select this matching option as selected
                return false; //Return after first match is found
            }
        });
    });
});
```

New Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chirag1goel/Lvn9vfcx/2/

Comment: the val typed in the input is not always going to equal the exact option name

Comment: @charlie Please check the edit. Now included sub-string matching. To make it case insensitive, you can use toLowerCase() function to make both string lower case before matching. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```js
// Event handler for text input
$('#txt').on('input', function() {
  // Getiing option based on input value and setting it as selected
  $('#sel option:contains(' + this.value + ')').eq(0).prop('selected', true);
});

// Event handler for select
$('#sel').change(function() {
  // Updating text input based on selected value
  $('#txt').val($('option:selected', this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<select id="sel">
  <option value=1>abc</option>
  <option value=2>def</option>
  <option value=3>ghi</option>
  <option value=2>jkl</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE :**

If you want to match the typed value then use

```js
// Event handler for text input
$('#txt').on('input', function() {
  var val = this.value;
  // Getiing option based on input value and setting it as selected
  $('#sel option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == val;
  }).eq(0).prop('selected', true);
});

// Event handler for select
$('#sel').change(function() {
  // Updating text input based on selected value
  $('#txt').val($('option:selected', this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<select id="sel">
  <option value=1>abc</option>
  <option value=2>def</option>
  <option value=3>ghi</option>
  <option value=2>jkl</option>
</select>
```

Or something complex with sorted result

```js
// Event handler for text input
$('#txt').on('input', function() {
  var val = this.value;
  // Getiing option based on input value and setting it as selected
  $('#sel option:contains(' + this.value + ')').sort(function(a, b) {
    var a1 = $(a).text(),
    a2 = $(b).text();
    console.log(a1.indexOf(val),a2.indexOf(val));
    if (a1.indexOf(val) > a2.indexOf(val))
      return 1;
    else if (a1.indexOf(val) < a2.indexOf(val))
      return -1;
    if (a1.length > a2.length)
      return 1;
    else if (a1.length > a2.length)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  }).eq(0).prop('selected', true);
});

// Event handler for select
$('#sel').change(function() {
  // Updating text input based on selected value
  $('#txt').val($('option:selected', this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<select id="sel">
  <option value=2>ajkl</option>
  <option value=1>abc</option>
  <option value=2>def</option>
  <option value=3>ghi</option>
  <option value=2>jkl</option>
  <option value=2>jkl</option>
  <option value=2>ajkl</option>
  <option value=2>jklaa</option>
  <option value=2>jklsdd</option>
  <option value=2>dddsjkl</option>
  <option value=2>eeeejkl</option>  
  <option value=2>.co.in</option>
  <option value=2>.co</option>
</select>
```

Comment: check my question. i have copied your code snippet into my question, if you type test.co it will show the .co.uk result however i would like it to show the .co result - is this possible at all? and the same for all others that are similar

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.querySelector(".input");
var select = document.querySelector(".selectItem");

var storage = {};
var nodes = select.childNodes;
for(i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
    var value = nodes[i].innerHTML;
    if(typeof value != "undefined") {
        storage[value.toLowerCase()] = nodes[i].getAttribute('value');
    }
}

input.addEventListener("input", function() {
    if(typeof storage[input.value.toLowerCase()] != "undefined") {
        select.querySelector('[value="'+storage[input.value.toLowerCase()]+'"]').setAttribute("selected", true);
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input"/>

<select class="selectItem">
    <option selected value="1">Internet Explorer</option>
    <option value="2">Chrome</option>
    <option value="3">Firefox</option>
    <option value="4">Safari</option>
    <option value="5">Opera</option>
    <option value="6">Edge</option>
</select>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5cdyu5yx/